# URI is not reachable with android but it is with UWP

Tags: android, xamarin, uwp, uri, ping

For a project, I'm using a server and I test the IP adress : 
For this, i'm using this :

```
Uri myUri;
IPAddress iPAddress;
if (Uri.TryCreate(uri, UriKind.Absolute, out myUri))
{
   res = await CrossConnectivity.Current.IsReachable(myUri.Host, 3000);
}
```

`CrossConnectivity` is from `Xam.Plugin.Connectivity`, version 3.2.0.

`res` is true when i'm using UWP but it is false when i'm trying an emulator.

My emulator had Android 8 (Oreo 8.0-API 26).

Did someone know somethig about this issue ?

PS : I'm connected to Internet, `CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected` return true

Comment: It is a known issue here :https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/ConnectivityPlugin/issues/145 , check this comment :https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/ConnectivityPlugin/issues/145#issuecomment-445395997 ,try to  create a new Android 19 emulator (using Visual Studio 15.8.9 and the Android API 28 and Xam.Plugin.Connectivity version 4.0.0.190-beta) to check if it works.

Comment: `myUri.Host` is not Localhost|127.0.0.1 is it?

Comment: No is not. This is about the emulator, if i'm using a real phone and it works